# Trying to figure out how to install this jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to install this script over here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Basic-Content-Carousel-Slider-Plugin-With-jQuery-gaBasicSlider.html

I don't know much about jquery, however, I tried to followed the instructions as best I could.

On step 3 of the instructions they say to initialize the plugin with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
  $('#example').gaBasicSlider();
});
```

And that these settings are available to use:

```
// enable auto rotation
animate: true,
// animation delay time
animationDelay: 6000,
// animation duration time
animationTime: 300,
// CSS selector for custom indicator
indicators: null,
// CSS selector for custom next button
btnNext: null,
// CSS selector for custom previous button
btnPrevious: null
```

So my questions is, how do I use the settings above? I tried doing something like this, but then the settings doesn't seem to take effect. Am I doing it wrong? See below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
      $('#example').gaBasicSlider();
     animationDelay: 2000,
     animationTime: 100,
    });
```

Did I use the settings in the correct place? Or is it supposed to be a seperate function or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gregartist.github.io/ga-basic-slider/

According to the documentation it looks like you pass it an object at creation with the values you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
  $('#example').gaBasicSlider({
    animationDelay: 200,
    animationTime: 100
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('#example').gaBasicSlider({
  btnNext : $('#example-next'),
  btnPrevious : $('#example-previous'),
  indicators : $('#example-indicators'),
  animate: false
});
```